# How to enable EJB 3.x support in WebSphere 7.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere, ejb-3.1, websphere-7

I'm new in WebSphere and I want to know that is there any way to run JavaEE6 (EJB 3.1) application under WebSphere Application Server 7.0 ?

I know that WebSphere 8 enabled JavaEE 6 support by default but I have to use WebSphere 7.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this. WAS 7.0 has no support for EJB 3.1, neither directly, nor in the form of a Feature Pack. You have to upgrade to WAS 8.x.

[Specifications and API documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rovr_specs.html?cp=SSAW57_7.0.0%2F3-1-6&lang=en).